# Which of these matrices are of the form $P^{T}AP$? (from CSIR(2019))

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$ where $$A= \begin{pmatrix}
 0&1 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Which of the following are of the form $P^{T}AP$, where $P$ is a invertible matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$?

> $1). \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 &0 \\ 
> 0 & -2
> \end {pmatrix}$
>
> $2). \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 &0 \\ 
> 0 & 2\end {pmatrix}$
>
> $3). \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &0 \\ 
> 0 & -1
> \end {pmatrix}$
>
> $4). \begin{pmatrix}
> 3 &4 \\ 
> 4 & 5
> \end {pmatrix}$

The solution I tried:

The given matrix is symmetric, so all eigenvalues are real. I also tried to find the $P$ matrix from the eigenvectors of matrix $A$, but the orthogonal matrix $P$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}$. And $A$ is symmetric so it is a diagonalizable matrix, so that option $3$ is true.

Comment: Are you sure that $P$ is supposed to be only invertible? Or is $P$ rather orthogonal? ($P^tP = I_2$)

Comment: if $P$ is orthogonal then it will also invertible.

Comment: matrix $P$ should be invertible.

Comment: Yes. But if $P$ is orthogonal, then $det(P^tAP) =det(A)$, which is not valid in your more general case. if $P$ is only invertible you have only $det(P^t) = det(P)$.

Comment: in question they said that $P$ should be invertible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement that the entries lie in $\mathbb{Q}$ makes the problem annoying. You can immediately eliminate (2) by observing that $P^TAP$ must have negative determinant. As for the others, I don't see a sleeker approach than simply inspecting

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix}a & c\\ b & d\end{bmatrix}$$
and explicitly solving for $a,b,c,d$ that gives the desired matrix. You have three equations and four unknowns, so you can solve for three of the entries in terms of the fourth ($a$, say), and see that there exists a rational solution. Note that the invertibility requirement on $P$ is something of a red herring, as the entries of $P^{-1}$ are always rational functions of the entries of $P$.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}
 2ab&ad+bc \\ 
cb+da &2cd 
\end{pmatrix}$ after multiplying i got this matrix ,but how can i get three equation ,there is no matrix in equality.